# Return path doesn't get set using mail.smtp.from

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, yahoo, mime-message

I am having problems setting the return path for all yahoo emails I'm sending. Here's what I'm using:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.host", host);
props.put("mail.port", port);
props.put("mail.user", username);
props.put("mail.password", password);
props.put("mail.smtp.from", bounceAddress);
```

I'm sending the mimeMessage using transport.sendMessage method. Still, after sending a few, in the Full-header for yahoo mails the return path is the same as the sender email.
Any idea what might be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're using the "smtps" protocol, but setting the property for the "smtp" protocol.  Set "mail.smtps.from" instead.

Comment: What does the [protocol trace](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?

Comment: apparently yahoo overwrites the return path I am sending. Yahoo has a security check and if the return path is not in the same domain as the smtp host, it uses the sender as a return path. I cant fix this in java code, so I had to hack this in order to make it work :)